# How to load one to many association in flex orm?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, orm

I'm trying to use flex orm in mobile app to interract with a local DataBase.
I have two tables with a foreign key. First table has 2 columns: id, city. And the second one has 2 columns too: street, city_id where city_id is a foreign key. In flex orm it looks like this:

```
[Table(name="CITY")]
public class CityVO
{       
    [Id]        
    public var id:int;

    [Column(name="city")]
    public var city:String;                             

    [OneToMany(type="StreetVO", lazy="true", cascade="all")]
    public var streets:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
}   

[Table(name="STREET")]
public class StreetVO
{       
    [Id]        
    public var id:int;

    [Column(name="street")]
    public var street:String;           

    [ManyToOne(cascade="none", name="city_id")]
    public var cityId:CityVO;                   
}
```

Does anybody know how to load all streets from one city with help of flex orm?